# At the outset of GoT Season 7 - can the White Walkers get past the Wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones

This question contains spoilers for Season 7 that can't be completely hidden by spoiler areas. So please stop reading if you haven't watched it.

After watching season 7, I was wondering - how could the Army of the Dead have invaded Westeros without the lucky fluke of a dragon flying into their territory and being killed?

If we know that the Wall's magic keeps them out, then how did they plan to attack Westeros, before they got a dragon?

Wouldn't the Wall's magic have prevented them from storming the gates in the Wall?

It seems very strange to me that the White Walkers had been gathering their army and preparing to invade for so long, without having the means to carry it out.

I thought up the following possibilities:

- The White Walkers can, in some way, see the future. Perhaps their plan was built around some prophecy of this event.
- They had some unknown item that were planning to use but was less effective than the dragon, so they used the dragon instead.
- I'm wrong about the Wall's magic and they could have broken through the gate like Mance Rayder attempted to.
- They weren't really going to invade and the invasion is mainly a device to speed up the plot, since there are only 6 episodes left. However, I'm doubtful that they'd go quite so far from G.R.R Martin's plan for the plot. (It's a pity that the most exciting part of the grand plot is being compressed so much.)

More thoughts about this matter would be very interesting.

It's ironic that the invasion seems to have begun because of Jon Snow's efforts to prepare for it...

Comment: Your title still contains a massive spoiler. You should fix that.

Comment: They can't pass through the wall, but nothing says they couldn't go around it or over it. Ramping is a common zombie tactic according to Max Brooks.

Comment: With the Horn of Joramun?

Comment: @JDoe: Tried to fix that, feel free to edit differently.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168425/would-the-night-king-have-been-able-to-succeed-on-his-own/168437#168437

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, they can just walk around it.

It turns out you can just walk around the wall.

What, you don't believe me? Think I'm pulling your leg? Read [this](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Gorge) then. Now, fair enough, it's not a walk in the park, you need to go down a gorge and then back up, but White Walkers are pretty spry, I'm sure they could manage it.

And since the Night's Watch are swell guys, they were kind enough to build a bridge across the gorge:

[image]

In the NW's hey-day that bridge might have been heavily guarded, but these days the Others shouldn't have too much trouble disposing of the defenders with some of the wights.

Comment: So why didn't the Night's Watch just destroy the bridge?

Comment: @SamMcCormack: Ask a book expert. I don't know what's the big idea in building a bridge to bypass the wall in the first place.

Comment: The bridge exists in the books as well? The bridge has always been there, the wall is slightly north of it I believe.

Comment: @Edlothiad: I think it's only mentioned in the book. Have we head of Westwatch-by-the-Bridge in the show at all?

Comment: @Edlothiad: Also, the bridge connects the two "sides" of the wall. It might be a little to the North of the wall but only if the gorge goes a bit south as it extends east.